# Join country calling codes to country table list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, join, formula, openoffice-calc

I am creating a Rails project which requires a country table. I also like to include the country calling codes into them. I found help in creating the country table from GitHub and it looks like this:

```
class CreateCountries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :countries do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :printable_name
      t.string :iso2, :size => 2
      t.string :iso3, :size => 3
      t.integer :numcode

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  Country.reset_column_information

  Country.create(:iso2 => 'AF', :name => 'AFGHANISTAN', :printable_name => 'Afghanistan', :iso3 => 'AFG', :numcode => '004')
  Country.create(:iso2 => 'AL', :name => 'ALBANIA', :printable_name => 'Albania', :iso3 => 'ALB', :numcode => '008')
  Country.create(:iso2 => 'DZ', :name => 'ALGERIA', :printable_name => 'Algeria', :iso3 => 'DZA', :numcode => '012')
```

and then I've also found a list of country calling codes and managed to put them in a spreadsheet:

```
Afghanistan 93
Albania 355
Algeria 213
```

What I'd like to a fast way to join the calling code into the above list so it looks like this:

```
Country.create(:iso2 => 'AF', :name => 'AFGHANISTAN', :printable_name => 'Afghanistan', :iso3 => 'AFG', :numcode => '004' :call_code => 93)
```

Any fast solution to achieve this using Excel or OpenOffice spreadsheet or MySQL?

Just as long as I don't have to key it in manually.

Comment: Could you clarify what you really want? The end of your question is not really straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy your `Country.create` lines of code into Excel, say starting in A1.
2. Copy your list of codes into Excel and if necessary split into two
   columns (eg with Text to Columns).
3. Name the result (say `CArray`).
4. In B1 put: `=FIND("printable_name => '",A1)+19`.
5. In C1 put:

   ```
   =SUBSTITUTE(A1,")"," :call_code => "&VLOOKUP(MID(A1,B1,FIND("'",A1,B1)-B1),cArray,2,0)&")")
   ```
6. Copy B1:C1 down to suit.
7. Copy as much of ColumnC back in to your code as suitable.

`cArray` need not be in the same sheet.